# I am getting null as result in useSelector from react redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

and also useEffect also not working in my file. i tried many way but useEffect not working. if i comments everything file and try then useEffect working else not working.
and also i am getting null value from

```
const { currentVideo } = useSelector((state) => state.video);
```

this is my useEffect ->

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const videoRes = await axiosInstance.get(`/videos/find/${path}`, {
          withCredentials: true,
        });
        // console.log(videoRes);
        const updatedView = await axiosInstance.put(`videos/view/${path}`);
        // console.log(updatedView.data, "view is updating");
        const channelRes = await axiosInstance.get(
          `/users/find/${videoRes.data.userId}`,
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
        setChannel(channelRes.data);
        dispatch(fetchSuccess(videoRes.data));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return "opps something went wrong!";
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [path, dispatch]);
```

here i am getting null value

```
const Video = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { currentVideo } = useSelector((state) => state.video);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const path = useLocation().pathname.split("/")[2];
  // console.log(currentVideo); // getting null
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState({});
```

and my full video.jsx is

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ThumbUpOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUpOutlined";
import ThumbDownOffAltOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbDownOffAltOutlined";
import ReplyOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ReplyOutlined";
import AddTaskOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddTaskOutlined";
import ThumbUpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbUp";
import ThumbDownIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ThumbDown";
import Comments from "../components/Comments";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { fetchSuccess, like, dislike } from "../redux/videoSlice";
import axiosInstance from "../axios";
import { subscription } from "../redux/userSlice";
import Recommendation from "../components/Recommendation";

import { format } from "timeago.js";

const Video = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { currentVideo } = useSelector((state) => state.video);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const path = useLocation().pathname.split("/")[2];
  // console.log(currentVideo); // getting null
  const [channel, setChannel] = useState({});

  /*
  // console.log(path); ok hai video user id aa rahi hai.
  // its working its getting all the data.
  const test = async () => {
    const isWorking = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/videos/find/63931e44de7c22e61c4ffd6c"
      );
      console.log(isWorking.data);
      console.log(isWorking.data.videoUrl);
    };
    const videoRes = test();
    console.log(videoRes);

    */

  // {withCredentials: true}
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const videoRes = await axiosInstance.get(`/videos/find/${path}`, {
          withCredentials: true,
        });
        // console.log(videoRes);
        const updatedView = await axiosInstance.put(`videos/view/${path}`);
        // console.log(updatedView.data, "view is updating");
        const channelRes = await axiosInstance.get(
          `/users/find/${videoRes.data.userId}`,
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
        setChannel(channelRes.data);
        dispatch(fetchSuccess(videoRes.data));
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return "opps something went wrong!";
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [path, dispatch]);

  const handleLike = async () => {
    try {
      await axiosInstance.put(`/users/like/${currentVideo._id}`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      dispatch(like(currentUser._id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return "opps something went wrong!";
    }
  };
  const handleDislike = async () => {
    try {
      await axiosInstance.put(`/users/dislike/${currentVideo._id}`, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      dispatch(dislike(currentUser._id));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  const handleSub = async () => {
    currentUser.subscribedUsers.includes(channel._id)
      ? await axiosInstance.put(`/users/unsub/${channel._id}`, {
          withCredentials: true,
        })
      : await axiosInstance.put(`/users/sub/${channel._id}`, {
          withCredentials: true,
        });
    dispatch(subscription(channel._id));
  };

  if (!currentUser) return "Loading....";
  return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <VideoWrapper>
          <VideoFrame src={currentVideo?.videoUrl} controls />
        </VideoWrapper>
        <Title>{currentVideo?.title}</Title>
        <Details>
          <Info>
            {currentVideo?.views} views •{format(currentVideo?.createdAt)}
          </Info>
          <Buttons>
            <Button onClick={() => handleLike()}>
              {currentVideo?.likes.includes(currentUser._id) ? (
                <ThumbUpIcon />
              ) : (
                <ThumbUpOutlinedIcon />
              )}{" "}
              {currentVideo?.likes.length}
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => handleDislike()}>
              {currentVideo?.dislikes.includes(currentUser._id) ? (
                <ThumbDownIcon />
              ) : (
                <ThumbDownOffAltOutlinedIcon />
              )}
              Dislike
            </Button>
            <Button>
              <ReplyOutlinedIcon /> Share
            </Button>
            <Button>
              <AddTaskOutlinedIcon /> Save
            </Button>
          </Buttons>
        </Details>
        <Hr />
        <Channel>
          <ChannelInfo>
            <Image src={channel.img} />

            <ChannelDetail>
              <ChannelName>{channel.name}</ChannelName>
              <ChannelCounter>{channel.subscribers} subscribers</ChannelCounter>
              <Description>{currentVideo?.desc}</Description>
            </ChannelDetail>
          </ChannelInfo>
          <Subscribe onClick={handleSub}>
            {currentUser.subscribedUsers.includes(channel._id)
              ? "SUBSCRIBED"
              : "SUBSCRIBE"}
          </Subscribe>
        </Channel>
        <Hr />
        <Comments videoId={currentVideo?._id} />
      </Content>
      <Recommendation tags={currentVideo?.tags} />
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Video;
```

and this is my redux videoslice file **videoSlice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  currentVideo: null,
  loading: false,
  error: false,
};

export const videoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "video",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchStart: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    fetchSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.currentVideo = action.payload;
    },
    fetchFailure: (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = true;
    },
    like: (state, action) => {
      if (!state.currentVideo.likes.includes(action.payload)) {
        state.currentVideo.likes.push(action.payload);
        state.currentVideo.dislikes.splice(
          state.currentVideo.dislikes.findIndex(
            (userId) => userId === action.payload
          ),
          1
        );
      }
    },
    dislike: (state, action) => {
      if (!state.currentVideo.dislikes.includes(action.payload)) {
        state.currentVideo.dislikes.push(action.payload);
        state.currentVideo.likes.splice(
          state.currentVideo.likes.findIndex(
            (userId) => userId === action.payload
          ),
          1
        );
      }
    },

    views: (state, action) => {
      if (state.currentVideo.views.includes(action.payload)) {
        state.currentVideo.views.push(action.payload);
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { fetchStart, fetchSuccess, fetchFailure, like, dislike, views } =
  videoSlice.actions;

export default videoSlice.reducer;
```

in browser i am also getting null
[image]

i am trying to call my api and render data. but useeffect not working in my code. also from useSelector i am getting null value.

Comment: Which is the line where the error is being thrown?

Comment: issue is like clouser in javascript. how can I avoid clouser. issue in my this code. in useReducer and useEffect and and while fetching data.

Comment: My guess is that in your reducer, `fetchSuccess` is not setting the video properly. Maybe debug what `action.payload` really is in this case. Also please don't post images of code, they might be offline when someone is trying to read this post in the future.